# STS 3.2.0 crashes when displays javadoc containing applet tag

Tags: java, applet, activex, javadoc

I write an applet class in STS 3.2.0. In order to test the applet conveniently I add a  tag in the class's javadoc comment like this:

```
/**
 * <applet code="jse.applet.SimpleApplet" width="200" height="60">
 * </applet>
 * @author samuel gong
 *
 */
public class SimpleApplet extends Applet {
...
}
```

Everything is ok until I move the mouse over the class name SimpleApplet. The supposed javadoc panel doesn't show instead a dialog window opens and tells me that a problem about ActiveX control occurred.

> --------------------------- Web Browser
>   --------------------------- One or more ActiveX controls could not be displayed because either:
>
> 1) Your current security settings prohibit running ActiveX controls on
>   this page, or 2) You have blocked a publisher of one of the controls.
>
> As a result, the page might not display correctly.
>
> ### --------------------------- OK

I know this is centainly a security problem but I don't know how to change settings to avoid it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ensure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show for applets & JWS apps.  If there is no output at the default level, raise it and try again.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Could you please add more details(e.g., instructions) to your suggestion?

Comment: Did you follow the link, read the instructions?  Do you expect I can explain that better than the *manufacturer?*  That page was how **I** found how to do it!